# Fake projective spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I'm looking for examples of "fake" projective spaces.

**Question:**  Are there smooth manifolds other than $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ whose cohomology ring is the truncated polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}[h]/h^{n+1}$ with $h$ of degree 2?

I know that there is a classification of so-called fake projective planes in the world of algebraic geometry and results restricting the existence of higher-dimensional examples.

However, I'm interested more in the topological question so don't need these manifolds to arise as varieties, but I do want to have the same *ring* structure.  I don't mind about what coefficient ring we work over.

Has anyone come across examples of such things?

**Edit**  Sorry, I should clarify: I guess I'm really looking for something with the same cohomology ring as $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ but, say, nontrivial fundamental group.  Thanks for those answers about exotic smooth structures though.

Comment: You can make $\pi_1$ non-trivial by a fairly cheap trick: Take any finitely presented group $G$ which has vanishing $H_1$ and $H_2$ (there are infinitely many of these). Realise $G$ as $\pi_1$ of a homology sphere; this can be done in dimensions $>5$ by a theorem of Haefliger, IIRC. Connect sum the homology sphere with $\mathbb{C} P^n$.


Answer (score 6):

Quote from the first page of the article [*Uniqueness of the complex structure on Kähler manifolds of certain homotopy types*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214445041) by Libgober and Wood (Journal of Differential Geometry 32, 1990, no. 1, 139-154):

"On the other hand it is known that for every $n>2$ the homotopy type of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ supports infinitely many inequivalent differentiable structures distinguished by their Pontryagin classes (see Montgomery and Yang [25] or Wall [30] for $n=3$ and Hsiang [15] for $n>3$)."

Comment: While the same statement for $n=2$ is a wide open conjecture. :)

Answer (score 4):

The Manifold Atlas page

http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_complex_projective_spaces

has plenty of useful information and references.

Comment: Hi Diarmuid, thanks for fixing the link.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search on "homotopy projective space" yields results that should interest you.  A 1973 paper of Bruce Conrad gives constructions of such spaces (starting with a given one): [*On manifolds with the homotopy type of complex projective space*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1973-0314063-3), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 176 (1973), 165-180.

Also related is Petrie's Conjecture.  He conjectured that if there is a smooth (non-trivial) circle action on a homotopy projective space $M\simeq \mathbb{C}P^n$, then the Pontryagin class of $M$ must be that of $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Some more information is available at http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Petrie_conjecture.